# Unique Tangency of circles from Sangaku

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, math-history, sangaku

A Geometric Sangaku shape [here on this wooden board up right](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Sangaku_of_Konnoh_Hachimangu_1859.jpg) from Japan's Buddhist Temples in 1859 during Edo period drew my attention recently, however I've found the exact values of the radius of all the circles by using inversion transformation and solving some algebraic equations by machine, It is still remained wonders on how they draw or craft this shape on the board such precisely those days.

[image] [image]

the ratio of radiuses of two big circle is:

$\frac{\overline{OL}}{\overline{OC}}=\frac{2\sqrt{7}\cos(\frac{\arccos(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{14})}{3})-1}{3} \approx 1.246979603717467$

if we take the radius of the smaller circle $\overline{BJ}=1$ then the radiuses of two big circles are: $\overline{OL}\approx 3.603875471609681,\overline{OC}\approx 2.890083735825261$

I used inversion with the center of $O$, the blue circle as inversion circle with power $\overline{OL} ^2$ and used equations to find relation of radius of the little orange circle (which is the inverse of the maroon circle with center of $G$) with other circle's radii.

In quest for an absolute geometric way of finding radii relations and drawing the whole shape with compass and ruler ,I've encountered another [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4307984/tangency-forcing-of-homothetic-circles) which seems irrelevant to this problem, but it would shows another complex aspect of tangent circles on plain.

> Question: Can anyone find an absolute geometric solution to find
> radii relations and drawing the whole shape with compass and ruler?
> hint: from my solution it came out that yAxis is tangent to the orange
> circle on the center of green circle $C$.

Comment: The ratio $\rho$ of radii between the small circle (小員) and the medium circle (中員) solves the cubic equation $$8\rho^3 + 12\rho^2 - 8\rho + 1 = 0.$$ It is not hard to show that this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, and so, the ratio $\rho$ is not a [constructible number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number).

Comment: @SangchulLee Well, how did you reach this cubic equation? Overall however the numbers are not construtible, there still exist questions on how they reached the nearly precise approximate answer!

Comment: @MasM: A cubic equation arises likely from the same sort of analysis behind your  formula for the ratio of the lengths. Please provide details of the work you did, so as to help people avoid duplicating your effort or explaining things you already know. ... *"[T]here still exist questions on how they reached the nearly precise approximate answer!"* Sure, but these are not the question you've asked here. If you want to know about approximation strategies, ask a separate question. For historical context regarding such things, you might ask on [HSM.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Writing $a$, $b$, $c$ for the radii of the large, medium, and small circles, respectively, we identify two key triangles in the figure.

- A right triangle with legs $b$ and $a-c$, and hypotenuse $b+c$. By Pythagoras,
  $$b^2+(a-c)^2=(b+c)^2 \quad\to\quad c = \frac{a^2}{2(a+b)} \tag1$$
- A triangle with sides $b$, $a+c$, $b-c$, and altitude $c$ relative to base $b$; expressing the square of the area in two ways (the second being Heron's formula), we have
  $$\begin{align}\left(\tfrac12bc\right)^2=\tfrac1{16}(b+(a+c)+(b-c))&\cdot(-b+(a+c)+(b-c))\\ &\cdot(\phantom{-}b-(a+c)+(b-c)) \\
  &\cdot(\phantom{-}b+(a+c)-(b-c))
  \end{align} \tag2$$

Substituting from $(1)$ into $(2)$ eliminates $c$; leaving (for $a>0$) this relation:
$$a^3 + a^2 b - 2 a b^2 - b^3= 0 \tag3$$ which is consistent with OP's calculated values $a=3.60387\ldots$ and $b = 2.89008\ldots$.

(Alternatively, eliminating $b$ gives $a^3 - 2 a^2 c - 8 a c^2 + 8 c^3= 0$, and eliminating $a$ gives $b^3 - 8 b^2 c + 12 b c^2 + 8 c^3= 0$. The latter confirms @SangchulLee's comment under the question.)

Because $(3)$ is an irreducible cubic, we conclude that a straightedge-and-compass construction of this figure is impossible.

That said, I see no reason to believe that the creator of a sangaku was in any way restricted in the tools or techniques used to draw the figure. I don't doubt that numerical approximations were allowed and/or expected (no real-world diagram has infinite precision, after all). *That* said, there *are* ways to extract, say, cube roots with the help of [a *marked* ruler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube#Using_a_marked_ruler), so the figure in question may well be geometrically "constructible" in an appropriate sense of the term.

I'd be interested to learn if there were specific geometric recipes for the kinds of computations implicit in sangaku figures. I recommend OP post a separate question to address this issue. The [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) may be able to provide historical context.

Comment: Well simply done, I used 3 equations which one of them is the same as your first one and the two others come from the inversion, I'll write my solution here. Thanks for introducing history forum. I'll ask about the historical mathematical knowledge of Japan as an isolated far east country. by the way It would be fascinating if they achieved how to approximately calculate a cubic equations by their own where there exist long history in quest of finding cubic equation's solutions in Great civilizations from Babylonian , Egyptian, Greek to Chinese, Iranian, Italian...

Comment: As you mentioned, I'm also still skeptical whether there were a pure geometrical construction from whom drew the shape(by usage of another tool like the marked ruler you've mentioned except compass and straightedge), or they used numerical approximations from equations? I think there should be some hidden points, lines, circles, ellipse, parapolas... that can lead us to a pure geometric solution.

Comment: recently I've found out that origami methods can be used to precisely solve all cubic equations and the interesting coincidence here is that origami was praticed widely like solving such these geometrical problems during Edo period in Japan, which also had isolationist foreign policy in that era.https://www.weizmann.ac.il/sci-tea/benari/sites/sci-tea.benari/files/uploads/softwareAndLearningMaterials/origami-math-en.pdf